# Uipath Regex: Many lines with same word, grab until line with 1st occurrence

Tags: regex

I have different section (Sales, Revenue, etc) in my text. Each section will have the same people names.

```
Sales
Peter $235
John $300

Revenue
Peter $450
John $400
```

For say, Sales section, I want to grab until the end of the line with the last person name.

```
Sales
Peter $235
John $300
```

I tried this

```
(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Text,"Sales.*((\n).+)*\n.*?John.*").Value)
```

but it will grab until the **last occurrence** of John

Thank you

Comment: Have a try with `Sales\n(?:.+\n)*`

Answer (score 0):

You could match Sales followed by all the following lines that do not start with John.

```
^Sales(?:\r?\n(?!John).*)*\r?\nJohn.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A0hefn/1)

If you don't want to match empty lines as well:

```
^Sales(?:\r?\n(?!John|$).*)*\r?\nJohn.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hDhj17/1)